# How to create an user defined page?

Tags: pages, customization, theme-options, menus

I have created a file example.php in the default site directory. I want to have the facilities of an Dashboard-Created-Page like the theme,navigation bar,navigation bar, header,footer etc..

Answer (score 0):

In your `example.php` file add this line at the top, this will enable all wordpress functions such as `$wpdb`, `get_header();` etc.

```
<?php require_once('LINK-TO-DIRECTORY/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

**Recommended reading - [Codex - Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)**

Comment: a `+1` will be appreciated :)